# Computer Slow? Any thoughts?

Tags: matlab

I have an older-ish computer, but when I bought it was a top of the line Lenovo W520 with 16GB ram, etc. (I can give more details as needed).

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

My computer runs slow and I am nervous about losing anything in an upgrade (and I'm wondering whether an upgrade is necessary).

What are some of the most simple things I can do to get my computer running fast again. (I am running Fortran and Matlab simulations on my computer)

Thanks!

Comment: Use the commands 'top' and 'free' to gauge your CPU and memory consumption. Terminate unused processes that hog resources.

Comment: Getting an SSD will boost the speed dramatically if you currently have a HDD